# Question regarding resource-specific consent and protected APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

I have an understanding problem with permissions on Graph API access to teams.
For example, if I want to use APP permissions to retrieve all messages in a channel, the current documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http says that I need "ChannelMessage.Read.Group (with resource-specific consent)" permission.
What does the note below mean "Before calling this API with application permissions, you must request access. For details, see Protected APIs in Microsoft Teams."? I think I had tried the access some time ago and failed because I didn't have access to the Protected APIs. Currently it works though, both with "ChannelMessage.Read.Group (resource-specific consent)" and without (I just set permissions for app). Is the note at this point possibly outdated?

Best regards
Anne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried investigating this on my end and I was unable to access the protected API using application permissions.
Interestingly, I found a [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/254210/why-is-the-access-request-required-for-protected-a.html) in Microsoft QnA related to what you are experiencing and the issue seems to have been reported.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you think that they will answer at the last comment as it is already more than two weeks old.

Comment: I sure do hope so, will keep tabs on it